# Why does VS 2015 have two UWP options, one inside windows and one inside windows 8

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp

i can create uwp app in VS 2015 by choosing C#/Windows/Windows 8/blank template but i don't have uwp templates for win10 installed, what is the difference between the two uwp options?
my pc is windows 10

Comment: Windows 8 apps are not universal. You have to make separate versions for PC and mobile.

Comment: if you have a vs 2015, click new project, choose c#/windows/windows 8 and there is a blank app(universal windows 8.1) template, if i choose c#/windows/universal/ there is "Install Universal Windows Tools". Is it okay to choose the first one?

Comment: As @RaymondChen said, they are not the same, in Windows 8, it's not real "universal". For developing UWP apps, you need to "Install Universal Windows Tools".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confusingly, there has been more than one type of project with the name "universal".

Windows 8 universal projects consist of three sub-projects. One for desktop-specific code, one for phone-specific code, and one for common code. The idea was that you put most of your app in the "common" project, with a small amount of code in the desktop-specific and phone-specific projects. When you built the solution, you got two packages, one for Windows 8 desktop and one for Windows 8 phone. It was universal in the sense that you wrote the code only once, but it still produced two packages that had to be submitted separately. The project is universal but the packages aren't.

Windows 10 universal projects are a single project that produce a single package that runs on both Windows 10 desktop and Windows 10 phone (and any other Windows 10 platforms). Both the project and package are universal.

If you ask for the Windows universal project template, you get a Windows 10 style universal project (recommended). If you ask for the Windows 8 universal project template, you get a Windows 8 style universal project (obsolete).